# Service Fabric Container API not loading on endpoint

Tags: containers, azure-service-fabric

1. Create a new web application in VS2017
2. Right-click web application->Add->Container Orchestration support-> Service Fabric
3. Run (F5) locally (success), loads on `http://machinename:<port in manifest>`
4. Publish to Azure SF cluster + container registry
5. This URL should load `http://<azurecluster>:<port in manifest>`

But it is not loading. 
The only thing that loads in the cluster is the Service Fabric Explorer, which shows the application running without error.
Am I doing anything wrong?

I think this has something to do with an incorrect port.
When adding a container ourselves through the template (as in the pic below), these are the options:

1. Host Port and container Port. Are these mapped correctly in
   Container Orchestration support (step #2 above)?
2. In Host port help icon, it says the port might need to be opened on
   load balancer. Do I need to do such things in my steps above?
3. Moreover, only the container port is provided in
   config (applicationManifest.xml) in Step #2. So what about the host port?
4. How is the container port mapped to the application port?
5. Why didn't we have to do it locally (if this is the problem)?

[image: Select a Template]

Answer (score 0):

The service specifies the container port in the manifest:

```
<Resources>
  <Endpoints>
    <Endpoint Name="Guest1TypeEndpoint" UriScheme="http" Port="8081" Protocol="http"/>
  </Endpoints>
</Resources>
```

The application specifies the host port in the manifest:

```
<Policies>
    <ContainerHostPolicies CodePackageRef="Code">
        <PortBinding ContainerPort="80" EndpointRef="Guest1TypeEndpoint"/>
    </ContainerHostPolicies>
</Policies>
```

In this example, container port 8081 is mapped to host port 80.
More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-containers).

You also need to configure an [Azure Load Balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/create-load-balancer-rule) rule and probe, to forward traffic (on port 80) into the cluster.

After that, you should see it work properly.

Comment: @loakD so the final url will be http://<azurecluster>:80  or http://<azurecluster>:8081 ?

Comment: in this example it would be 80 (the host port).